# Relocate Symbol Definition from XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I´m trying to relocate the Definition of a Symbol from the XAML to the Resourcefile.
Unfortunately the Symbol isn´t displayed correctly after the relocation, instead the String for the Symbol is displayed.
New:

```
<Run x:Uid="Page_BackButtonUISymbol" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
```

Old:

```
 <Run Text="&#160;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
```

Ressource File:

Name:Page_BackButtonUISymbol.Text

Value: & #160;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately the Symbol isn´t displayed correctly after the relocation, instead the String for the Symbol is displayed

This is because the ampersand is escaped

1. Right click the RESW file and select "Open With..."
2. Choose "**XML (Text) Editor**"
   [image]

You will find the resource's value will be replaced by [`&amp;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined%5Fentities%5Fin%5FXML):

```
<data name="UISymbol.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>&amp;#xE160;</value>
  </data>
```

[image]

**Please modify it to `&` character**

```
<value>&#xE160;</value>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**See my completed sample** [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/SymbolResourceUWPApp1)